# I am using quick sort to sort an array. But am getting the array unsorted. I have tried to find the error but have failed

Tags: c++, sorting, quicksort

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;

int partition(int input[], int start, int end)
{
    int x = input[start],count=0;

    for (int i=start+1;i<=end;i++)
    {
        if (input[i] <= x)
            count++;
    }

    int temp = input[start+count];
    input[start+count] = x;
    input[start] = temp;

    int i=start, j=end;

    while (input[i] != x && input[j] != x)
    {
        if (input[i] > x && input[j] < x)
        {
            int temp1 = input[j];
            input[j] = input[i];
            input[i] = temp1;

            i++;
            j--;
        }
        else if (input[i] <= x)
        {
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            j--;
        }
    }

    return count+1;
}

void helpSort(int input[], int start, int end)
{
    if (start >= end)
        return;

    int c = partition(input, start, end);

    helpSort(input, start, start+c-1);
    helpSort(input, start+c+1, end);

    return;
}

void quickSort(int input[], int size)
{
    int start=0,end=size-1;

    helpSort(input, start, end);
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1,3,7,2,6,4,8,9,0,5};

    quickSort(arr, 10);

    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My approach was to find numbers smaller than the first element of the array. Partition it and then call qs on the partitioned array. For eg:- 1 5 7 8 9 3 partitions it wrt to 1. then qs it with two arrays before 1 and after 1. This continues recursively till start is either equal to or greater than end which is the first and last index of my array. End denotes the last element of my array.
This is my code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you use a debugger? btw `end` is usually used to denote the (non-existing) element one past the last one, hence using `end` to refer to the last element of the range is a little confusing.

Comment: The next step (for you, not for us) would be to figure out which line triggers the runtime error. A debugger would make this trivial. In the absence of a debugger, stream a bunch of diagnostics to `std::cerr` (not `std::cout`, as you want the unbuffered stream). Initially, you could have the diagnostics show just what lines are executing. However, once you know the last line that executes, the diagnostic right before that line should include the values of each variable that appears in that line.

Comment: no, I have not used a debugger cause. yes, the end is used for array size but I used it as my last element should clarify it.

Comment: I think the error lies in the helpSort function in the recursive call as when I changed it the runtime error stopped but the array is not sorted. Btw it worked when I inputted an array of size 1,2,3,4.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the while loop condition. When it encountered the same element as the one which was the partitioning element the loop closed. (duplicate numbers)

Also the if conditions did not consider duplicate elements i.e if (i>x or j<x).
It should have been i>x or j<=x.

The count return should have been returning count and not count+1. This solved the problem I had.